# What to use when signing print on metal

Tags: printing, metal

I saw an old thread about using a BIC Mark-It to sign print on metal.  Then I saw a set of BIC Mark-ITs on amazon but when it was delivered, the label said BIC intensity.  Does anyone know if BIC Mark-IT is still available, or if BIC intensity is the same as BIC Mark-IT or maybe just the updated version of BIC Mark-IT?  Is BIC intensity good to use when signing print on metal?  The package says that it is acid free.

Thanks!!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about comparing drawing products and no relation at all to the photography.

Comment: This post is about signing a photo that is print on metal.

Comment: No, the question is about drawing lines with instrument on metal surface.

Comment: Dude, I should know that the original post was about signing a photo that is "print on metal" since I'm the original poster.  Give it a rest.